# Trying to access data after a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm really struggling with the concept of a promise and how to access data returned by one. I am trying to access order information on a Thank You page in Wix. I am then trying to send that data to Facebook. You can see from the below which console.log's work and which do not. Suggestions please!

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
import {postToFacebook} from 'backend/facebookModule.jsw';
import {hashData} from 'public/pages/masterPage.js';
import {getUserIP} from 'public/pages/masterPage.js';

$w.onReady(async function () {

    $w('#thankYouPage1').getOrder()
        .then((order) => {
            const orderObj = order;
            console.log('this works! '+ orderObj.number)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });


    console.log('this DOES NOT work '+ orderObj.number)


    const data = {
        "data": [
            {
                "event_name": "Purchase",
                "event_time": Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
                "action_source": "website",
                "event_source_url": wixLocation.url,
                "user_data": {
                    "em": (await hashData(orderObj.BillingInfo.email)),
                    "client_ip_address": (await getUserIP()),
                    "client_user_agent": navigator.userAgent
                },
                "custom_data": {
                    "currency": orderObj.currency,
                     "value": orderObj.totals.total
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    console.log(orderObj.totals.total);

    //console.log(await postToFacebook(data));
    await postToFacebook(data);


});
```

The error is of course on my second console.log:

> workerLogger.js:103 ReferenceError: orderObj is not defined

**SOLUTION - You need await:**

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
import {postToFacebook} from 'backend/facebookModule.jsw';
import {hashData} from 'public/pages/masterPage.js';
import {getUserIP} from 'public/pages/masterPage.js';

$w.onReady(async function () {
    try {
        var orderObj = await $w('#thankYouPage1').getOrder();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    const data = {
        "data": [
            {
                "event_name": "Purchase",
                "event_time": Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
                "action_source": "website",
                "event_source_url": wixLocation.url,
                "user_data": {
                    "em": (await hashData(await orderObj.billingInfo.email)),
                    "client_ip_address": (await getUserIP()),
                    "client_user_agent": navigator.userAgent
                },
                "custom_data": {
                    "currency": await orderObj.currency,
                     "value": await orderObj.totals.total
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    //console.log(orderObj.totals.total);

    //console.log(await postToFacebook(data));
    await postToFacebook(data);


});
```

Comment: Short answer is to do `const orderObj = await $w('#thankYouPage1').getOrder()`. Please please please read through the dupe, though. You've got to learn how async programming works as some point. Otherwise, you'll just have this same problem again tomorrow somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I have tried that already: const orderObj = await $w('#thankYouPage1').getOrder() - what should be inside the then? return order;? The console.log return undefined: console.log(orderObj)

Comment: There is no `then` in the code snippet I posted.

Comment: Got it working. I was missing off await in front of orderObj. Thanks!